# Search for subdirectory in a given directory in LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

I would like to find the subdirectories for a given directory. so far my code looks like this..

It does connect, but now I am not sure how to get the groups under the `MainGroup`

```
DirectoryEntry _de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xxx.com/DC=xxx,DC=org");

DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(_de);

ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(CN=MainGroup)";

ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;           
ds.PageSize = 1000;
ds.SizeLimit = 0;

foreach (SearchResult result in ds.FindAll())
{
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're not being very clear - either you want to search for the **containers** and **organizational unit** elements (the "subdirectories") that are **structural** elements in LDAP, or you want to find **groups** which is a totally different concept. Groups are not structural, groups contains a list of members, but they're not defining a hierarchy like containers and OU's do. So which you do you want?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have said groups. so "SubGroup" is a member of "GroupMain". So if the user searches for "GroupMain", "subGroup" should be retunred as Member of "GroupMain".   If you can, can you also mention how this could be done for Containers and OU?

Comment: As I said: groups aren't defining a hierarchy - there's no "subgroup" of a group. Groups have members - users and other groups - which you can read. But groups don't have hierarchical structure - there are no "subgroups" of existing group

Comment: Thats correct,so how do i find that a group is a member of another group?

Comment: See my answer for the way to determine the groups that are member of `MainGroup`

Comment: Here is a tip, specify the OU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "MainGroup");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
        // iterate over members
        foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
        {
             Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
             // do whatever you need to do to those members

             // if you need to find the groups that are members of 'MainGroup'  
             GroupPrincipal group = p as GroupPrincipal;
             if(group != null)
             {
                 // now you have a group that is member of 'MainGroup' - do what you need here
             }

        }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: seems like you have a lot of expereince in this... Your answer works great. So I guess nobody uses Directory Searcher and Filters with AD anymore?

Comment: @AJ17: if you're going against Active Directory, then using the newer `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace is just much easier to use. The "old" S.DS classes are needed if you need to connect to other LDAP stores (like Sun OneLDAP or OpenLDAP or something like that)